# Laravel - 5.8 one to many relation returns null

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have `Cars` model which belongs to two other models `Region, Subregion`.
Cars Model:

```php
function region(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Region');
}
function subRegion(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Subregion');
}
```

Subregion model:

```php
class Subregion extends Model{

public $timestamps = false;

protected $fillable = [
    'name'
];

public function cars(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Car');
  }
}
```

Region:

```php
class Region extends Model{

public $timestamps = false;
protected $fillable = [
    'name'
];

public function cars(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Car');
  }
}
```

I have query which selects Cars with their region and subregion:

```php
$queryCar= Car::with(array(
        'region'=>function($query){
            $query->select(['id', 'name']);
        },
        'subregion'=>function($query){
            $query->select(['id', 'name']);
        }
))->orderBy('id', 'DESC');

return $queryCar->get();
```

Table `cars` has columns `region_id`, `subregion_id`.

When I try to loop the cars result:

```php
    foreach ($cars as $p){
        var_dump($p->subregion);
        var_dump($p->region);
    break;
    }
```

For the region, I see the result, which is not NULL, but there is no subregion.
I am sure that there is, because, if I do:

```php
var_dump($p);
```

I can see and `subregion_id` and if I query database with that id, there is a subregion row.

It is strange, because everything is equal for these two - Subregion/Region.

Comment: Try naming your with `subRegion` instead of `subregion`, might be a case sensitive issue.

Comment: It is still the same.

Comment: Okay next thing, in your relation subregion, inside the belongsto method Define a second parameter with the column `subregion_id`.

Comment: Can you log the executed queries?

Comment: Ok, fixed, thx :)

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer.

Comment: What fixed it for you? Was it the column naming or something else? If that's the case I'll post the solution so you can mark this resolved

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. Actually I don't know how was fixed and why... I have  followed your solution to set everything to `SubRegion` and the table to `sub_regions`, foreign keys as `sub_region_id`, but it was the same. Then I turn everything back and it just start working. Your advice fixed the problem, but not in the way as an answer. Thanks :), anyway .